# Custom function to read file from current path in Python needs refactoring

Tags: python, function

I had to write a custom function to load a yaml file from the current working directory. The function itself works and my intention was to write it in a pure fashion but my senior colleague told me that the way I wrote this function is utterly bad and I have to rewrite it.

Which commandment in Python did I violate? Can anyone tell me what I did wrong here and how a "professional" solution would look like?

```
from typing import Dict
import yaml
from yaml import SafeLoader
from pathlib import Path
import os


def read_yaml_from_cwd(file: str) -> Dict:

    """[reads a yaml file from current working directory]
    Parameters
    ----------
    file : str
        [.yaml or .yml file]
    Returns
    -------
    Dict
        [Dictionary]
    """
    path = os.path.join(Path.cwd().resolve(), file)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            content = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
            return content
    else:
        return None

content = read_yaml_from_cwd("test.yaml")
print(content)
```

Comment: This is more suitable for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyway - don't check that file exists - it is prone to race condition, just try to work with it and handle the error if the file is missing. Explicitly return `None` is also questionable.

Comment: @buran thank you, did not know about "codereview" :-)

Comment: I'm not in your league but a few comments: 0/ `from...import...` could be removed to use `yaml.SafeLoader` and `pathlib.Path` directly 1/ None is not a Dict. 2/ Maybe returning None instead of raising an exception is not according to the specification. 3/Resolve is not applied to the whole path. 4/ content (and maybe path) are intermediate variables that could be skipped.

Comment: If you are opening a file in the current working directory then there's absolutely no need for all the os.path.* stuff. Just *with open(file) as f:* is all you need. Also, why assign to *content*? Just *return yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)*

Answer (score 1):

The significant parts of your function can be reduced to this:

```
import yaml
from yaml import SafeLoader

def read_yaml_from_cwd(file):
  try:
    with open(file) as f:
      return yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
  except Exception:
    pass
```

In this way, the function will either return a dict object or None if either the file cannot be opened or parsed by the yaml loader